# Iconv and Kconv on Ruby (1.9.2)

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, iconv

I know that Iconv is used to convert strings' encoding.
From my understandings Kconv is for the same purpose (am I wrong?).

My question is: what is the difference between them, and what should I use for encoding conversions.

btw found some info that Iconv will be deprecated from 1.9.3 version.

Comment: It looks like Kconv is just for kanji?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes says, it looks `Kconv` is like `Iconv` but specialized for Kanji ("the logographic Chinese characters that are used in the modern Japanese writing system along with hiragana" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji). Unless you are working on something specifically Japanese, I'm guessing you don't need `Kconv`.

If you're using Ruby 1.9, you can use the built-in encoding support most of the time instead of `Iconv`. I tried for hours to understand what I was doing until I read this:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Then you can start to use stuff like

```
String#encode           # Ruby 1.9
String#encode!          # Ruby 1.9
String#force_encoding   # Ruby 1.9
```

with confidence. If you have more complex needs, do read http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings

*UPDATED* Thanks to JohnZ in the comments

`Iconv` is still useful in Ruby 1.9 because it can *transliterate* characters (something that `String#encode` et al. can't do). Here's an example of how to extend `String` with a function that transliterates to UTF-8:

```
require 'iconv'
class ::String
  # Return a new String that has been transliterated into UTF-8
  # Should work in Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9 thanks to http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/
  def as_utf8(from_encoding = 'UTF-8')
    ::Iconv.conv('UTF-8//TRANSLIT', from_encoding, self + ' ')[0..-2]
  end
end

"foo".as_utf8 #=> "foo"
"foo".as_utf8('ISO-8859-1') #=> "foo"
```

Thanks JohnZ!

Comment: The problem with `String#encode` and friends is that they will not help much if your string is not `String#valid_encoding?`; Even if you will `#force_encoding` your string you might get a non `#valid_encoding?` string. `Iconv` has the ability to transliterate the invalid chars. Yes, you can remove/replace them with `#encode`, but it's not the same as the `Iconv`'s transliteration table.

Comment: Regarding your UPDATE: Your method `as_utf8` is useful only if you are going to "heal" utf-8 strings that are not `String#valid_Encoding?`. This is because you have the second parameter (which is `from` encoding) set static to `'UTF-8'`.